# Endless loop on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Device: Raspberry pi 3a+
After installing python3 on Raspberry Pi os, I opened interpreter on terminal and ran below code

```
a = "abc"
while True:
    print(a)
```

And my raspberry pi os is completly deleted. I tried to format sd card on Windows but it only reads my sd card as 30MB disk, originally is 16GB. Several trying but same result and finally it was almost burning and splited.

Is it too dangerous to run endless loop on Raspberry Pi os?

Answer (score 1):

This is not dangerous. You're just running an infinite loop that's printing `a` on the terminal. Hit `CTRL + C` on the interpreter shell and the infinite loop will be interrupted due to a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But there was no time to enter Ctrl + C. Right after running it, the whole os was removed.

Comment: Something weird was happening on the pi. Something like this will not get the OS deleted.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running Python infinite loop on rasp pi would definitely not delete your OS. Can you record any action after you run that on the command line?
If you are sure you would like to format your SD card, you may consider using Disk Management tool on Window to format your SD card to full capacity.

Comment: Terminal was immediately gone, and I was unable to open it agian(even I hit Ctrl + Alt + T). Also I saw the menu bar is disappeared and tried to reboot but it showed me only black monitor. After failing to format my sd card, I used disk manager to find if there is unallocated part of my sd card. But there was no unallocated part only detected it as an about 30MB disk.